# Change list of recognizers depending on user

Tags: botframework

Our bot has a large set of skills (LUIS and QnA Maker intents), but not all skills are useful for all users. We would like to suppress some skills depending on who the user is.

We developed some code to do this for LUIS intents, dynamically filtering intents returned from our model to only include ones appropriate for the current user.

The issue we have though, is that we also have a couple of QnA models in our array of recognizers (recognizer_array) ...

```
var intents = new builder.IntentDialog({ recognizers: recognizer_array, 
intentThreshold: 0.85, recognizeOrder: 'series'});

bot.dialog('/mainDialogue', intents);
```

But not all users need these QnA models, we would like to exclude them for *some* users.

Is there a way to dynamically filter intents so that we could exclude these QnA intents for some users?

Comment: What I would normally recommend is using the [onEnabled](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/classes/_botbuilder_d_.intentrecognizer.html#onenabled) method derived from the IntentRecognizer class, but since this is for QnA Maker, you will have to roll your own implementation as QnAMakerRecognizer does not inherit from the IntentRecognizer class. See issue [#62](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-CognitiveServices/issues/62)

Comment: Thanks, I. The only workaround I can think of is to import all utterances to a LUIS intent, one for each FAQ. In the case of an FAQ intent, the bot can then call QnA maker. It's messy though and I suspect it would add a lot of noise to the model. Hmmm.

Comment: One new tool that is easily used with the [V4 SDK](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-js/tree/master/samples/dispatch-es6) is the [dispatch tool](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-tools/tree/master/Dispatch). This tool creates a parent LUIS model that sits atop LUIS and QnA Maker models and then routes utterances as needed. It might be able to help with your idea. Though I said it's easily used with the V4 SDK, it should be possible to organize your V3 bot to use the Dispatch tool.

Comment: The dispatch tool did the trick nicely, we are able to activate/deactivate dispatch intents depending on user. Thanks.